# Facebook Javascript SDK locale language

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to use facebook javascript sdk and get the data in my language, but it keeps sending the data in English although it's available in my language.

I change my JS import to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://connect.facebook.net/es_LA/all.js"></script>
```

and the data I get is still English - For example place categories (when I access the place I can see the categories in spanish, api shows in english)

Is there anything else I should do in order to change the received data language?

Thanks in advance.

I did try the following code instead/in addition:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  (function(d){
  var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_LA/all.js";
  d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
}(document));
  </script>
```

but it's still English when it's in, or `FB is not defined` of it's instead the `src`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only specifying the SDK locale here - that will influence how social plugins such as the Like button etc. will be rendered.

If you want to get API result in a specific locale, you need to specify it via the `locale` parameter in your API call, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#readmodifiers

Comment: Thank you for refering me to the right place. But does it mean that I will have to add the local parameter for each call? Isn't it possible to set it once for all?

Comment: Yes, you have to set it for each call. (Unless you use some sort of SDK or framework, that would allow to configure the local in one single place, and then appends it to all API requests automatically …)